# Selecting every single unit from a certain type in StarCraft 2

Tags: starcraft-2

When I play StarCraft I want to select every single unit from a certain group( all lings, all hydras etc.), but without doing Ctrl + double click because it will select the one on the screen. I also don't want to assign an army to a number and then click twice in the HUD, because it will select the one from the number, not all existing of that type.

The only thing that comes to my mind is F2 and then double click the unit in the HUD.

Is there a faster way?

Answer (score 2):

To expand on alicsharp's answer:

You can press the all-army hotkey (<kbd>F2</kbd> by default), then <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+Click on the any unit of the type you want to select in the command card at the bottom. If you are using Mac, and you've set the setting that makes <kbd>CMD</kbd> act as <kbd>CTRL</kbd>, say, for setting command groups, then instead of <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+Click, you should use <kbd>CMD</kbd>+Click.

Answer (score 1):

The TAB key does this.

TAB does select each unit type but there is no hotkey for every unit of a type. You would have to use F2 first to select your whole army and then use tab to cycle through each type of unit in your army. -- Enhanced instructions from Mac Man on how to actually cycle through the units.

Comment: This does not select only those units. I can use it, for example, to switch between which spellcasters I can use to cast spells, but if I send a move command, it moves all units.

Answer (score -1):

Just CTRL+ Click on unit with Mouse.